# Faster way to test if xmm/ymm register is zero?

Tags: assembly, optimization, x86, avx, micro-optimization

It's fortunate that `PTEST` <del>does not affect the carry flag, but only sets the (rather awkward) ZF.</del> also affects both CF and ZF.

I've come up with the following sequence to test a large number of values, but I'm unhappy with the poor running time.

```
              Latency / rThoughput
setup:
  xor eax,eax       ; na
  vpxor xmm0,xmm0   ; na       ;mask to use for the nand operation of ptest
work:
  vptest xmm4,xmm0  ; 3   1    ;is xmm4 alive?
  adc eax,eax       ; 1   1    ;move first bit into eax
  vptest xmm5,xmm0  ; 3   1    ;is N alive?
  adc eax,eax       ; 1   1    ;move consecutive bits into eax
```

I want to have a bitmap of all the non-zero registers in `eax` (obviously I can combine multiple bitmaps in multiple registers).

So every test has a latency of 3+1 = 4 cycles.
Some of this can run in parallel by alternating between `eax`,`ecx` etc.
But it's still quite slow.
Is there a faster way of doing this?

I need to test 8 xmm/ymm registers in a row. 1 bit per register in a one byte bitmap.

Comment: What is the desired output? Do you want to have a bitmap of which values are nonzero? Or is it sufficient to know if any register is nonzero?

Comment: Of course a lot depends on the surrounding code - how many registers values will you be comparing for zero in a loop, and what do you want to do with the result? Without restrictions on the output format, the "fastest" way to check if a register is zero is to use one of the `PCMPEQ` instructions to compare to a zeroed register, but this may not leave the result in the form you want it...  **Added:** fuz beat me to it by a minute :)

Comment: How many registers do you test in a row low like this?

Comment: I'm testing 8 registers in a row, perhaps 16 later on if I can think of other things to test for. I've replaced the `rcl` with a `adc eax,eax` which is faster in reciprocal throughput.

Comment: @Johan - I added a solution which does the work up front in the vector registers, which should be faster on Intel at about 2 uops/vector, while with `adc` I get 3 uops/vector for yours (since `PTEST` is two uops). Of course you need to measure and tweak it to avoid port contention to be sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than being "quite slow" your existing approach is reasonable, actually.

Sure each individual test has a *latency* of 4 cycles<sup>1</sup>, but it if you want the result in a general purpose register you are usually going to pay a 3 cycle latency for that move anyway (e.g., `movmskb` also has a latency of 3). In any case, you want to test 8 registers, and you don't simply add the latencies because each one is mostly independent, so uop count and port use will likely end up being more important that the latency to test a single register as most of the latencies will overlap with other work.

An approach that is likely to be a bit faster on Intel hardware is using successive `PCMPEQ` instructions, to test several vectors, and then folding the results together (e.g., if you use PCMPEQQ you effectively have 4 quadword results and need to and-fold them into 1). You can either fold before or after the `PCMPEQ`, but it would help to know more about how/where you want to results to come up with something better. Here's an untested sketch for 8 registers, `xmm1-8` with `xmm0` assumed zero, and `xmm14` being the `pblendvb` mask to select alternate bytes used in the last instruction.

```
# test the 2 qwords in each vector against zero
vpcmpeqq xmm11, xmm1, xmm0
vpcmpeqq xmm12, xmm3, xmm0
vpcmpeqq xmm13, xmm5, xmm0
vpcmpeqq xmm14, xmm7, xmm0

# blend the results down into xmm10   word origin
vpblendw xmm10, xmm11, xmm12, 0xAA   # 3131 3131
vpblendw xmm13, xmm13, xmm14, 0xAA   # 7575 7575
vpblendw xmm10, xmm10, xmm13, 0xCC   # 7531 7531

# test the 2 qwords in each vector against zero
vpcmpeqq xmm11, xmm2, xmm0
vpcmpeqq xmm12, xmm4, xmm0
vpcmpeqq xmm13, xmm6, xmm0
vpcmpeqq xmm14, xmm8, xmm0

# blend the results down into xmm11   word origin
vpblendw xmm11, xmm11, xmm12, 0xAA   # 4242 4242
vpblendw xmm13, xmm13, xmm14, 0xAA   # 8686 8686
vpblendw xmm11, xmm11, xmm13, 0xCC   # 8642 8642

# blend xmm10 and xmm11 together int xmm100, byte-wise
#         origin bytes
# xmm10 77553311 77553311
# xmm11 88664422 88664422
# res   87654321 87654321 
vpblendvb xmm10, xmm10, xmm11, xmm15

# move the mask bits into eax
vpmovmskb eax, xmm10
and al, ah
```

The intuition is that you test each `QWORD` in each `xmm` against zero, giving 16 results for the 8 registers, and then you blend the results together into `xmm10` ending up with one result per byte, in order (with all high-QWORD results before all the low-QWORD results). Then you move those 16 byte masks as 16-bits into `eax` with `movmskb` and finally combine the high and low `QWORD` bits for each register inside `eax`.

That looks to me like 16 uops total, for 8 registers, so about 2 uops per register. The total latency is reasonable since it largely a "reduce" type parallel tree. A limiting factor would be the 6 `vpblendw` operations which all go only to port 5 on modern Intel. It would be better to replace 4 of those with `VPBLENDD` which is the one "blessed" blend that goes to any of `p015`. That should be straightforward.

All the ops are simple and fast. The final `and al, ah` is a partial register write, but if you `mov` it after into `eax` perhaps there is no penalty. You could also do that last line a couple of different ways if that's an issue...

This approach also scales naturally to `ymm` registers, with slightly different folding in `eax` at the end.

**EDIT**

A slightly faster ending uses packed shifts to avoid two expensive instructions:

```
;combine bytes of xmm10 and xmm11 together into xmm10, byte wise
; xmm10 77553311 77553311
; xmm11 88664422 88664422   before shift
; xmm10 07050301 07050301
; xmm11 80604020 80604020   after shift
;result 87654321 87654321   combined
vpsrlw xmm10,xmm10,8
vpsllw xmm11,xmm11,8
vpor xmm10,xmm10,xmm11

;combine the low and high dqword to make sure both are zero. 
vpsrldq xmm12,xmm10,64
vpand xmm10,xmm12
vpmovmskb eax,xmm10
```

This saves 2 cycles by avoiding the 2 cycle `vpblendvb` and the partial write penalty of `or al,ah`, it also fixes the dependency on the slow `vpmovmskb` if don't need to use the result of that instruction right away.

---

<sup>1</sup>Actually it seems to be only on Skylake that `PTEST` has a latency of three cycles, before that it seems to be 2. I'm also not sure about the 1 cycle latency you listed for `rcl eax, 1`: according to Agner, it seems to be 3 uops and 2 cycles latency/recip throughput on modern Intel.

Comment: Oh, I was looking at the AMD timings, I guess `adc eax,eax` is a better choice than.

Comment: Shouldn't the `pblendvb xmm10, xmm10, xmm11, xmm14` be `vpblendvb xmm0, xmm10, xmm11, xmm14`?

Comment: Right, yes! Actually the `movmskb` was meant to use `xmm10` not `xmm0` (since it's nice to keep the zeroed aspect of `xmm0`, perhaps for following code).

Comment: @MargaretBloom - in fact, I was going to use `punpacklbw` which is more natural and doesn't need a mask but it just adds more contention to port 5.

Comment: Are you sure that `and al, ah` is correct ? Shouldn't it be `or al, ah`?

Comment: @PaulR - I think it is right, although I had also originally thought `or` and had originally mentioned "or folding" (but changed it before submit). The `CMPEQ` returns all-ones if the register tested against `xmm0` is all-zeros, so the bits that end up in `eax` are 1 `iff` the corresponding qword in the `xmm` was zero. So both bits need to be `1` for the whole register to have been zero, hence the and (it means that the bitmask has 1 to mean "register was zero" - which I think is what the OPs solution does too).

Comment: @BeeOnRope: ah, OK, inverted logic - my mistake.

Comment: Note that the `vpmovmaskvb` has a latency of 3 cycles, still I can hide this by doing some other work.

Comment: Right but also note  you are only  doing _one_ movmskb for every eight registers.

Comment: Slight nitpick, doesn't `vpblendvb` need a fixed mask of `010101010101...` in `src3:xmm14`, I don't see you setting that anywhere.

Comment: @Johan - well yes, I "set" it in the text before the code when I said "with `xmm0` assumed zero, and `xmm14` being the pblendvb mask to select alternate bytes used in the last instruction." Often I leave the mask setup out with the assumption that code will run in a loop and the mask setup can be hoisted out. In any case, hopefully the mask load is "free" since it uses a load port which is otherwise unstressed here. In the worst case you get a cache miss which is bad, so consider also `punpacklbw` which doesn't need any mask.

Comment: @Johan - whether than ending is faster depends on the hardware, but it's not clear to me that adding 3 instructions of 1 uop will be faster than one instruction `pblendvb` with 2 uops. Also, if you are using non-VEX code (as the code in your question indicates), you can use the non-VEX `pblendvb` which has `xmm0` has the hardcoded mask, which is only 1 uop to any of `p015`.

Comment: Doesn't really help this question in particular since that's more about latency, but I found the use of `vpmovmskb` actually quite useful in my case because it saves a uop on port 5 (which was bottlenecked on shuffle-heavy code) compared to `vptest`.