# Most efficient way to test if a 256-bit register (YMM: AVX-2) is zero

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, simd, avx2

I need to check whether a certain YMM register is zero (under AVX-2). I know that I could `vptest` it against  another YMM register, but that would have a latency of (most likely) *at least* 2 <del>and it would also require an auxiliary register</del>. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Test the register against itself?

Comment: @fuz: Yes, of course; thank you. But that would still have the latency issue.

Comment: Everything has a latency issue. Basing it on `vmovmskps` or `pmovmskb` is worse and doing some sort of horizontal reduction and extracting an element is even worse than that.

Comment: @harold: Yes, masking is worse. But since `vptest` takes two operands, I was hoping there is a single-operand way of doing this that I'm not yet aware of and should probably (as a result) have a lower latency.

Comment: Correction: 3-operand vs 2-operand; I've been looking at the intrinsics for too long apparently.

Comment: @oligilo Note that `vptest` takes two operands, not three, so I'm not sure what you want.

Comment: @fuz: You are right, I'm on fire today :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Faster way to test if xmm/ymm register is zero?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42317528/faster-way-to-test-if-xmm-ymm-register-is-zero)

Comment: If you've got only one reg to test then you cannot beat `ptest`. If you have many regs than you can test and fold using `pcmp`, see the duplicate.